# Why is my text still wrapping under a floated div?

Tags: image, css, reactjs, word-wrap

I have a render component which renders out some text and an image.  The component is a DIV containing two divs. The first div contains an image, this div is floated to the right.  The next div contains various text strings.  I have overflow: hidden on the parent div, but my text is still wrapping around the div containing the image.  The only way I can fix this currently is by setting the height to 100% for the div containing the image.  However, if I do this I can't add a border / background to this div because it extends the entire page.

In short, I have a div containing two divs.  I want my text in a column, and the image in the other.  I do not want the text to wrap under the image.  I've visited the other text wrapping questions, but overflow hidden or adding span tags doesn't seem to be solving my problem.

Below is the render function and the SASS/CSS that goes with it.

```
render() {
        const renderHelpFile = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
            return this.props.name === obj.name;
                }).map((obj, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div key={idx} className="fadingDiv">
                        <div className="divImg">
                            <img src={`${obj.image}`} className="helpFileImg"></img><br />
                        </div>
                        <div className="displayLineBreak">  
                            <h3 style={upperStyle}> {obj.name} </h3>
                            <b>Path:</b> {obj.path} <br /><br />
                            {obj.content} <br /><br />
                            <b>Troubleshooting:</b> {obj.troubleshoot} <br /><br />
                            <b>Video:</b> {obj.video} <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        });
```

css

```
.fadingDiv {
    text-align: justify;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-animation: divFadeIn .75s ease-in forwards;
    animation: divFadeIn .75s ease-in forwards;
}

.displayLineBreak {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.divImg {
    width: 35%;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #0080ff;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    //height: 100%;
}

.helpFileImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you can post some related portion of rendered HTML, it would be much easier to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `float` is supposed to work - text "floats" around it.

Instead of using float, you could either define both containers as `inline-block`, with according `width`settings, or you could put `display: flex` on the container element.

If you know the width of the image, you can use that for a fixed width on the image container and use `calc` for the width of the text container, like `width: calc( 100%  - XXpx );`, where XX stands for the width of the image.

Comment: so define the divs as in-line block and position the image div to the right of the text div?

Comment: flex has odd results - basically extends both divs to the same size.  This is like making the image div height 100%.  So the background of the image div extends all the way to the floor of where the text is going.

Comment: With the in-line block method, you get odd results with the the image div sometimes being at the bottom of the screen, or the top.  The text sometimes starts at the top or at the middle of the screen.

Comment: You'd need some additional settings: For the inline-blocks `vertical-align: top`, for flexbox `flex-grow: 0` on the image container and `align-content: flex-start;`

Comment: just had to add vertical-align: top to fix the alignment after adding in the inline-block to the child divs.  Thank you